How to programmatically generate storybook stories?
I'm working on a library for visualization. There are lots of combination of configurations. I don't want to manually create the stories.
Imagine I have two options, show/hideLabel, show/hideAxis. There will be 4 combinations. Currently I need to manually write 4 stories. In real world, there are so many combinations which makes manually writing stories so painful.
Can I create them via a couple for loops?
I need to have these stories because I use them to generate Percy diffs.
